# Querydsl set fetch mode in a query

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have a situation where a Card entity has a foreign key to a Person.

```
public class Card implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String cardid;
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.person;
    }
}
```

The default fetch type for the person is LAZY. Can I specify the fetch type to EAGER within a query:

```
QCard qCard = QCard.card;
JPQLQuery query = getQuery().from(qCard);
query.list(qCard);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can just call the `getPerson()` method to load the Person object before your object is detached, do you have a specific reason to change the fetch type ?

Comment: The reason I want to change the fetch type is to optimize the query. I have a case where I need to load multiple foreign key objects. It seems to work slow.

Comment: So you're looking for the `FETCH` keyword from JPAQL in QueryDSL. Is this what you're looking for ? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/querydsl/Geexg_eN2yA/iREXf-DM0nwJ

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for. I will give it a try and write back the results. So I can just add something like this for every foreign key object to eager load:"query.innerJoin(qCard.person).fetch();"

Comment: I added "query.innerJoin(qCard.cmsPerson).fetchAll();" but it still lazy fetches the person object.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you try

```
QCard qCard = QCard.card;
List<Card> cards = getQuery().from(qCard)
    .innerJoin(qCard.person).fetch()
    .list(qCard);
```

---

For QueryDSL 4.0.2+

```
QCard qCard = QCard.card;
List<Card> cards = getQuery().from(qCard)
    .innerJoin(qCard.person).fetchJoin()
    .select(qCard).fetch();
```

Comment: Originaly I tried innerJoin with fetchAll. I found out that the combination leftJoin with fetch works. Not sure if this is the case or some caching was the problem.

Comment: Please put your working code in an answer and mark this issue as resolved

Comment: Timo's answer works. Person is fetched eagerly if I use fetch(), but not if I use fetchAll().

Comment: As of [QueryDSL 4.0.2](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1414), the interface has changed. To set the fetch mode of the last join, call fetchJoin(). To finally get the results, call fetch(). So it would be List<Card> cards = getQuery().from(qCard)
    .innerJoin(qCard.person).fetchJoin()
    .fetch();