# How to write querydsl to select from child tables with one to many relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, querydsl

My question is somewhat related to this [querydsl Tuple](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/Tuple.html)
Here, Data from a table `employee` is being fetched. In my use case I have a child table called `projects` which is having one to many relation with `employee` table. Eg: employee A can have 3 projects say X, Y, Z. To model this, I have a `Employee` class with `List<Project>` as a member variable.
Now, I want to select the employee name and all the project that belong to them. What modification I need to make in the query that is shared in the link mentioned above. 
In terms of SQL I am interested in fetching following.

```
SELLECT EMP.EMPLOYEE_NAME, PRJ.PROJECT_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE EMP, PROJECT PRJ WHERE EMP.EMP_ID = PRJ.EMP_ID;
```

Any easy to understand documentation on this topic will also be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querydsl set fetch mode in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627482/querydsl-set-fetch-mode-in-a-query)

Comment: Please add your code to the question, I'm wondering why are you retrieving Tuples from the query instead of Employees.

Comment: @vmaldosan, Its more of a _How to properly do this?_ and _Is it possible to do this using querydsl?_ I was interested to know the proper way to do it, even though its not necessary for my app.